# .htaccess subfoders, subdomains and addon domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Here is my setup

- Main Domain : foo.com
- Sub Domain : sub.foo.com
- AddOn Domain : bar.com

Directory Structure for sub domain on Root is this:

`sub/` - for sub domain (which is the default)

Now I create a sub folder for bar.com in the root directory

`bar/` - for bar.com

And created the following rule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} bar.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !bar/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ bar/$1 [L]
```

The result would be.

- sub.foo.com - sub/
- bar.com - bar/
- bar.com/bar - bar/ (**How do I fix this? so that it redirects to bar.com ?** )
- bar.com/sub - sub/ (**How do I fix this? so that it redirects to sub.foo.com?** )
- foo.com/bar - bar/ (**How do I fix this? so that it redirects to bar.com ?** )
- foo.com/sub - sub/ (**How do I fix this? so that it redirects to sub.foo.com?** )

So the bottom line is I don't want the users to directly access the subdirectories on the Directory Tree. Is this possible? how?

**EDIT:** Please don't start lecturing about virtual host, I don't have access to httpd.conf on this server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the main site's `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.foo.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^bar
RewriteRule ^bar/(.*)$ http://www.bar.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.foo.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^sub
RewriteRule ^sub/(.*)$ http://sub.foo.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

The other 2 sites, being hosted from subdirectories should not ever have a need for trying to map away from something like `bar.com/bar/...` with this setup.

In the `bar.com` site you can do this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^bar/(.*)$
RewriteRule .* %1 [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^bar/?$ / [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.bar.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^sub
RewriteRule ^sub/(.*)$ http://sub.foo.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

For `sub.foo.com` you can do this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^sub/(.*)$
RewriteRule .* %1 [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^sub/?$ / [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub.foo.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^bar
RewriteRule ^bar/(.*)$ http://www.bar.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```